# ASP.NET 2.0 dynamically add OnSelectedIndexChanged

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a DropDownList() that is rendered in my codebehind and populated by myView

```
 Dim ddl As New DropDownList()
 ddl.ID = "ddlV_" & dtrw("col_id") & "_" & fixDisplayName(dtrw("display_name"))
 ddl.DataSource = myView
 ddl.DataTextField = "DDLTEXT"
 ddl.DataValueField = "DDLVALUE"
 ddl.AutoPostBack="true"

 ddl.DataBind()
```

I would like to add `OnSelectedIndexChanged ="do_this_when_changed"` attribute to the above dropdown list.

I do understand that Web server controls are also created on the server and they require a runat="server" attribute to work.

Can this be done for this list control?

Comment: Note that you are using two different variable names above(lbSearch + ddl). I assume that is a typo, isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an event handler programmatically with [`AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim ddl As New DropDownList()
' ... ' 
AddHandler ddl.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf do_this_when_changed
```

In this class:

```
Private Sub do_this_when_changed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim ddl = DirectCast(sender, DropDownList) ' here it is'
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but ListControl.SelectedIndexChanged Event is suppose to fire off when the select index is changed...when the page loads I dynamically select a item (and a event is triggered ), and I give the user the option to choose a different item (and trigger the event and populate ddl2) based on what item is selected in ddl. I might be missing something, but is the change supposed to happend when the selected index is changed.

Comment: @ChadSellers: No events in ASP.NET are fired programmatically. Only when the user selects something the `SelectedIndexChanged` is triggered. Is that desired? Otherwise you need to provide a method, say `do_this_when_changed`, which you can call from the event handler (and from elsewhere).

Comment: I think we are on the same page..what i'm trying to do is populate ddl2 (US cities) based on what item in ddl (US States ) is selected..so i'm looking for a method, lets say to populte ddl2 when ddl is changed...my problem is i'm new to vb.net and have no idea how this can be done. #clueless

Comment: @ChadSellers: If you set `AutoPostBack="True"` on the `DropDownList` it'll postback immediately when the user selects something else. But note that you have to recreate dynamically created controls on the next postback with the same ID as before in `Page_Load` at the latest (in the page's life-cycle).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using this event...

```
ddl.SelectedIndexChanged
```